# Why does my laptop trackpad only work while charging?

Tags: touchpad, dell-inspiron

I have a dell N4050 laptop. The problem is the laptop track pad stops working when I stop charging. It only works during charging. I have had this laptop for over an year now.

This started happening recently. Why is this happening?

Comment: What have you researched or tried to resolve this yourself?

Comment: I searched the internet but could not find anything related to my issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of responses related to very similar issues when searching for [dell N4050 touchpad only works while charging](https://www.google.com/search?q=touchpad+only+works+while+charging&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=eb479e865be94603&q=dell+N4050+touchpad+only+works+while+charging).

From what I gathered by very briefly reviewing some of the posts in Dell's forum, I'd suggest contacting Dell. This may be related to the AC adapter or possibly even the motherboard being defective.